# PORT environment variable changed Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, nginx

I'm using Google App Engine nodejs8 standard environment and I've seen they've changed the PORT environment variable value.

It used to be 8080 and now it's 8081 and thus it's firing some nginx warnings:

> nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /tmp/start-nginx/nginx.conf:2

This warning was not allowing to access any express routes. I've manually changed the listening port to 8080 and now express is running OK, but:

> start: Cannot start nginx. Performance may be degraded. Fallback mechanism is unsupported and may be removed at any time. App should listen on PORT environment variable. Fallback engaged: app is listening on port 8080

Comment: You can check in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#environment_variables the environment variables and see how PORT should be set to 8080

Comment: Same problem here! node 8 standard env. Suddenly the app started to show: **302 too many redirects.**.  My app is listening to process.env.PORT btw. edit: curious thing is that same code, in other project, in other region, works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was contacted by a Google engineer and told that it was a problem with the nginx version. It's fixed now.

So, listening to the PORT environment variable in your app should remain the good practice to follow.

Answer (score 0):

**temporal workaround:**

if someone hits this problem, heres a workaround:
change runtime to `nodejs10` in your app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs10
```

Comment: Hardcoding the port to 8080 is already a workaround. I wouldn't recommend changing the runtime as it can break your app due to dependencies with gcloud libraries as it's the case.

Comment: in my case, hardcoding the port didn't work. I was already using process.env.PORT